# how do I know if the headless chrome(puppeteer) browser page is not opened properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I've been doing web scraping/crawling using headless-chrome(puppeteer.js). The target data is massive(approx. 3,000 ~ 20,000 pages) so I've created node.js crawling app that does multiple asynchronous scraping at the same time with multiple chrome tabs. The problem here is that the app randomly stops opening the target page and just returns nothing to the result flagged as `await` value. I had to remove timeout option from headless-chrome because it caused the app to stop the whole scraping, returning `reject` errors.

In conclusion, the app randomly stops around when it scrapes 100~300 pages and stops opening the target page and returns nothing to `await` result, thus the app waits the `resolve` for unlimited time. I think it could be a bug, since it rather happens randomly. It doesn't happen when I open less than 100 chrome tabs in total.(but maximum of 6~7 windows at the same time). also it doesn't happen when the app is synchronously programmed.(I did the similar stuff with less amount of dataset last time. because the data set was so small, I just made the whole app synchronous and waited for its result)

**question**

how do I know the page status when it's not opened properly? and can I make the app 'ignore' the task that is not responding?(while keeping timeout options)

**app structure**

```
//main settings...
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
//limited data amount by redirecting to different URL
const targetUrl = `http://www.samplesite.com/board/lists/?id=test&exception_mode=recommend&page=`
const pageMin = 1
const pageMax = 403 //each page has roughly 20~30 elements to scrape
//!!!detrimental for RAM consumption & performance
const windowMax = 7 //maximum chrome window opened at once
...

//main scraping function
async function scrapePage(browser,targetUrl,pageNo){
  try{
    const page = await browser.newPage() // <--sometimes app just doesn't open up a new window and infinitely be on hold....
    console.log(`browsing page ${pageNo} ...`)
    await page.goto(targetUrl + pageNo, {timeout: 3000000})
    //prolonged the timeout to prevent sudden stop of task

    let titles = await page.evaluate((selector)=> {
      return [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].map(el=>{
        return { text: el.innerText, href:el.href, comment:0 } })
    }, '.t_subject > a')
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }
  if(page) await page.close()
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>resolve(convertedTitles))
}

...

async main(){

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless:false //set headelss:false for gui debug
    ,args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] //for prevent RAM errors
  })

  let countLimit = 0
  let pageScrapePlan = []
  let scraped = [] // <------final result

    for(let i=pageMin;i<=pageMax;i++){
      console.log(`crawling on page ${i} / ${pageMax} ---- ${(i / pageMax * 100).toFixed(2)}%`)
      pageScrapePlan.push(scrapePage(browser,targetUrl,i))
      countLimit++
      if(countLimit % windowMax === 0 || i === pageMax) {
        //if the counter reaches the maximum number of windows, run scraping at once
        let resPage = await Promise.all(pageScrapePlan)
        resPage.map(elScrappedFromPage=>{
          scraped = {...scraped,...elScrappedFromPage}
        })

        pageScrapePlan = []
    }
    await browser.close()
}

main()

//to catch unhandled rejection errors with line number
process.on('unhandledRejection', up => { throw up });
```

Comment: It seems this was not necessary after all. Later I've discovered  `env DEBUG="puppeteer:*" node script.js` option from [Puppeteer Github pages](https://github.com/checkly/puppeteer-examples) and it does work fine. It's just that the Chromium GUI debugger cannot catch up the internal processing speed, so it seems to be stopped from GUI window and Node.js console is rather too fast so that it looks like as if the work is put on hold but thousands of internal calls are already made, still being processed in the background. **Just make sure to use debug option for Puppeteer when developing**

Comment: and please separate the scraping task into several different chunks, it seems the memory leaks anyway due to both Chromium + Node.js and hang and delay are almost inevitable.

Comment: check out [Puppeteer Github page api info](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md) for checking out Chromium page events.

Comment: you can answer your own question, don't put the solution in the comments